# Открытие модального окна из точки где происходит вызов окна фигурой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не судите строго, не могу понять как это делается и не могу найти информацию, или незнаю как правильно прописать запрос в поиске.

Интересующий вопрос:
Как сделать открытие модального окна при клике по элементу, чтобы это окно открывалось как бы визуально из этого объекта по которому был клик, и растягивалось по экрану кругом пока не достигнет полного открытия.
Я думаю правильно выразился, но не знаю, помогите пожалуйста

Если можно пример для полного понятия

Comment: это "раскрывающийся список", "спойлер", "баян". простой делается на раз два, но... `и растягивалось по экрану кругом пока не достигнет полного открытия` вам похожу нужен анимированный, с этим "чуток" сложнее))

Comment: Да вы правы, здесь в данном случае скорее всего нужен анимированный с использованием svg. Но как это реализовать и примеров нет

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере модальное окно появляеться по клику из кнопки с помощью CSS свойств: transform: scale(0.5);  transform-origin: top left; transition: all 0.3s; получаем нужный эффект анимации

```js
const openModalBtn = document.getElementById("openModalBtn");
const closeModalBtn = document.getElementById("closeModalBtn");
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

openModalBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
   modal.classList.add("open");
});

closeModalBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
   modal.classList.remove("open");
});

window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.classList.remove("open");
   }
});
```

```css
.modal {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  }

  .modal.open {
     visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
     pointer-events: auto;
     transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s;
  }

  .modal-content {
     background-color: #fefefe;
     margin: 5px auto;
     padding: 20px;
     border: 1px solid #888;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     transform: scale(0.5);
     transform-origin: top left;
     transition: all 0.3s;
  }

  .modal.open .modal-content {
     width: 80%;
     height: 80%;
     top: 10%;
     left: 10%;
     transform: scale(1);
  }

  .close {
     color: #aaaaaa;
     float: right;
     font-size: 28px;
     font-weight: bold;
     cursor: pointer;
  }

  .close:hover {
     color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<button id="openModalBtn">Открыть модальное окно</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <span class="close" id="closeModalBtn">&times;</span>
     <p>Это модальное окно</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению там нет того что я ищу, подсказка не в том направлении. Я же написал, открытие окна и развёртывание его должно быть прям из объекта по которому клик был не поверх страницы, а именно из объекта открытие

Comment: Чтобы развёртывание модального окна происходило из центра кнопки

Comment: Я понял тебя и исправляю код

Comment: Да это похоже, но далеко от желаемого, это я знаю как делается, но написал появление как бы из объекта, то есть из самого объекта, и раскрытие кругом до полного раскрытия по экрану. Это делается точно через svg, но пример найти не могу нигде, для решения вопроса